# I can't ssh from a linux (ubuntu) to a windows 10 machine

Tags: openssh

I tried to ssh from a Linux(Ubuntu) to a windows 10 machine. But It keeps telling me to enter a password for the window machine. I entered the password correctly. when I debug the windows machine from PowerShell I got the following message

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Unable to load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: Unable to load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug1: Unable to load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

Answer (score 0):

With SSH, we can use "keys" to login to a remote system to add an extra layer of security, or to automate remote access.

Keys are a pair of encrypted files. One goes on the remote machine, and one stays on the local machine.

It looks like Windows is expecting a key.

Check your settings again.

Either Linux is expecting there to be a key in the Windows machine that doesn't exist
OR
the Windows machine is expecting a key from Linux that you haven't loaded into ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my case is same as you, but you may try running the Command Prompt with Administration Privilege to run `sshd -d` (-d for debug as you mentioned), which I did solved that error.

If run without Administration Privilege for `sshd -d`, I got the same error of `Unable to load host key: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`.